# Trazendo uma Query do Controlador para o View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, view

Estou começando a me aventurar e aprender sobre MVC e C#.
Criei uma aplicação de catálogo de filmes com um tutorial, onde tenho uma tabela no banco de dados chamada Movie e na aplicação eu faço um CRUD nessa tabela.
Um dos atributos de Movie é Genre, onde estou tentando criar uma tabela própria para ele e depois usar os valores dessa tabela como opção na hora de preencher o campo Genero ao cadastrar um Filme novo.

Abaixo está a consulta criada para buscar os valores da tabela Genre em coloca-los em uma lista:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
        {
            // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
            IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Genre        //usando o LINQ para pegar a lista de gêneros.
                                            orderby m.Name
                                            select m.Name;

            var movies = from m in _context.Movie          //pesquisa LINQ
                         select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
            }

            var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
            {
                Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Movies = await movies.ToListAsync()
            };

            ViewBag.ListaGenre = new SelectList(movieGenreVM.Genres);
           
            return View(movieGenreVM);
        }
```

Estou tentando carregar para o View essa consulta, para que eu possa utilizar ela na pagina de Create.
Pesquisando me apareceu a ideia de usar o ViewBag para isso.

```
            ViewBag.ListaGenre = new SelectList(movieGenreVM.Genres);
```

O Problema que quando chamo no view, ele não me exibe nada. Fiz um debugger e vi que o ViewBag está com o valor gravado nele tudo certinho, mas não é exibido.

```
@ViewBag.ListaGenre
```

Aprendi que uma página de View só pode usar 1 Model, e como essa Query faz parte de outro model que não é a utilizada pela View que quero printar, estou tentando usar o ViewBag para poder só levar essa consulta para lá.

A minha dúvida é: Estou usando de forma errada o BagView? será que esqueci de alguma coisa? Viewbag só pode ser chamado se for gravado na mesma página?

Answer (score 0):

No caso você está tentando gerar um **DropDownList** correto ?

No controller:

```
ViewBag.ListaGenre = new SelectList(db.Genre, "GenreId", "GenreName");
```

E no seu View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("GenreId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ListaGenre , null, new { @class ="form-control" })
```

Comment: Isso! um DropDownList. os parametros no controller GenreId e GenreName estão sendo definidos como os campos da lista ou deve ser o mesmo nome que está na tabela?